# How to create a list of names submitted through forms by different users in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, forms

I have some experience using WordPress, and am familiar with JavaScript and HTML on a basic level. I am working on a WordPress website and I need to have any visitor to the site be able to input a name. This name needs to be stored in a list or a database so that the list of names can then be displayed on the website. Is there a way to do this where I set up a form asking for a name and then, when they click submit, for it to automatically save the name to the end of the current list and display it on the page. This is my first time posting on here and I have been unable to find what I am trying to do. If anyone can help, or at the very least point me in a direction that I can research, that would be appreciated. I can learn about PHP or something if I know what it is that I need to learn to accomplish this. Thanks for any assistance.

*UPDATE*
For clarification, all I am trying to do is to have a box that any random visitor to the site can type a name in, and a button to add that name to a running list of all names that are currently there displayed on the page. I want the list to be able to contain hundreds of thousands of names entered by any and all visitors. There is no collection of info from them other than the name which is entered to be added to the list. I am sorry if I am too vague, but I am trying to explain what I want to do as best I can. I am willing to do research, but there is so much info on the internet, I am having trouble even knowing what to research, I have tried searching for multiple things without finding any relevant information. If anyone can even give me more technical terms to describe what I am trying to do I would appreciate it. Thank You.

Comment: Lots of wordpress plugins around that will take care of this for you as well as activate in admin for sort/search etc

Comment: Let me clarify a bit. I am having a hard time searching for things, because it is difficult to find what I am trying to do. I want a page that shows a list of names, and has one entry box that people can type a name into then have it added to the list that is displayed there. None of the visitors to the site are logging in and no other info is being collected from them. I have tried to search for wordpress plugins, but I cannot find anything that relates to what I am trying to do. Most things are about lists of your posts and things of that nature. Do you have a specific term to search for?

Comment: yes  ... wordpress forms

Answer (score 0):

The answer is easy I believe (just guessing) add the following code to your functions

```
add_shortcode('wpso52105670_namelist','wpso52105670_namelist');

function wpso52105670_namelist(){
ob_start();

echo '<form method="post" action="">';
echo '<input type="text" name="name" />'
echo '<input type="submit" />';
echo '</form>';

if(!empty($_POST['name'])
{ update_option('names', sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']).'<br />'); }

echo '<div class="names-list">';
echo get_option('names');
echo '</div>';

return ob_get_clean();
}
```

and put shortcode [wpso52105670_namelist] on some page where you want it to appear.